# Edit img tags in html document with nokogiri ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am wanting to edit `img` tags within a html document using nokogiri.

I currently have for example the following `img` tag in a doc:

`<img src="image1.jpg">`

There is no consistency with the naming of the images. What I want to do is convert the above `img` into the following:

`<img src="/User/account/folder1/folder2/image1.jpg">`

I have the `/User/account/folder1/folder2/` stored in a variable for example.

The document can have anything from 1 to 20 image tags within each document but the path is always the same.

At the end of the conversion I will want to take the amended html and store it into a variable

```
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file))
```

I am able to open the doc but I am unsure how to proceed further with iterating over it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you serving these files from an HTTP server? Does it have permissions to see those files, since typically, for security, it won't. If it can't see/open them, they won't be visible to anyone using that page because the server won't be able to send the file to the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up achieving what I wanted with:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(file))
  page.css('img').each do |div|
    image = div.attribute("src")
    div.set_attribute("src", ("#{absolute_path}""#{image}") )
    puts div.attribute("src")
  end

  amended_page = page.to_html
```

Its worth noting that `absolute_path` is a variable set outside of this and is typically something like `User/account/folder/`

Comment: I would use `File.join(absolute_path, image)` as this handles leading/trailing path separators.

Comment: If the HTML is being changed on a Windows system, the path separators will be '\' using `File.join`, which is not how HTML paths are defined. Instead, either force the separator or use `join('/')` and an array or something similar.